# Problem with GridViewControl

Tags: asp.net, sql, controls

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="464px" Width="743px" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="No Rows Selected" 
        DataSourceID="Answered" 

        style="z-index: 1; left: 327px; top: 334px; position: absolute; height: 464px; width: 743px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ThreadTitle" HeaderText="ThreadTitle" 
                SortExpression="ThreadTitle" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Answered" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CP_AllQuestionsAnswered %>" SelectCommand="SELECT ThreadTitle
FROM Threads AS t
INNER JOIN Users AS u ON  t.UsersID=u.UsersID
WHERE t.UsersID=@UserID">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
  </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Code File:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser CurrentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid userid = (Guid)CurrentUser.ProviderUserKey;
    Answered.SelectParameters.Add("UserID", userid.ToString().Trim());
}
```

When I modify the grid's datasource, I write my query and test it with a specific grid and it gives me the expected results. But when I run the grid view, all I get is "Empty rows". Why is that?!?

Comment: I expect to see all the threads submitted by the user. Depending on the user that is logged in,, a particular guid should be passed to sqldataDatasource query and give me all the rows.. i want to pass a parameter to the query in the sqldatasource that i built..but it doesnt work... The query works , i tested it when i build my sqldatasource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is this: in your `Page_Load`, you're constantly **adding** a new parameter to your SQL datasource, even though that parameter is already defined.

Try this instead - setting the value of the existing parameter:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MembershipUser CurrentUser = Membership.GetUser();
   Guid userid = (Guid)CurrentUser.ProviderUserKey;
   Answered.SelectParameters["UserID"].DefaultValue = userid.ToString().Trim();
}
```

Does that change anything?

Comment: yeah, it did my man.. since you are still here. could you tell me how i can add paging?

Comment: @WithFlyingColors: set the `AllowPaging` on the `<asp:GridView>` to true, and then handle the `OnPaging` event (or something similar - can't think of it right now - check the MSDN docs!!)

Comment: See: [Gridview - paging and sorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx)